# how to communicate between openmote and arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, iot, uart, contiki

I'am working on an IOT project. The goal is to communicate between two openmotes (one is the server and one is the client). When the client receives some data, it is supposed to pass it to an arduino to activate different controllers (like a motor, some leds ...). So, I wanna send data from a openmote to an arduino. The idea is to use a bus. The openmote is the master and the arduino is the slave. Do you have any idea how to do this ? I can't find any documentation fro the open mote part. I thought about using the serial UART but i don't have any idea how to do that.

Thank you !

Comment: Please anyone can help ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer, it is possible to activate the UART 1 on the open mote and to send data to the arduino using that bus. You have to pay attention to the speed you are using on both sides.You can refer to this file to see the functions to use: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/cc2538-common/test-uart.c